# use mysql inbuilt functions with cakePHP find()

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

can any one help me to use the mysql inbuilt function in cakePHP?????

Comment: Which ones, the ones built into PHP or those built into Cake?

Comment: i mentioned about the inbuilt mysql database functions such as DATE_FORMAT(),CONCAT(string1,string2,...),REPLACE(whole_string,to_be_replaced,replacement)............ http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p9.php

Comment: You can always sidestep the framework and use `$this->Model->query()`

Comment: There is, as in SpawnCxy's answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use

```
$this->Model->query($yoursql);
```

Then there's still another way for some mysql functions such as `concat`,`date_format`

```
$this->Model->find($findtype,array('fields'=>array('concat (column1,column2,...) as con','date_format(...) as mydate'),'conditions'=>...));
```

Comment: why this statement `$competition = $this->Competition->find('first', 'fields' => array('(fee1+fee2) AS total','id','title' )));` results `$competition=array(0=>array('total' => 8),'Competition' => array('id' => 1,'title' => 'Competition1'));`

Comment: @RSK,that's right.If you don't like this style,see http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/09/29/dealing-with-calculated-fields-in-cakephps-find/

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to use CONCAT in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields). I imagine you would be able to extend the syntax to use the other MySql functions as required.

Comment: The use of virtual fields is documented in the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields. They only appeared with version 1.3, however.

I would probably opt for the $this->Model->query($yoursql);
construct in this case - that's what it's there for.